# Cannot translate JavaScript to TypeScript with spread operator object

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a Javascript object challenge which I cannot translate to Typescript.

```js
var someData = [
    'Some String',
    {'age': '46'}
];


const addressObject = {
    street: 'Main Street',
    number: '14'
}

const resultObject = {
    address: addressObject,
    ...someData[1]
}

console.log(resultObject)
```

Result is, and should be:

```bash
{ address: { street: 'Main Street', number: '14' }, age: '46' }
```

In TypeScript, I cannot figure out how to get the second element in `someData` to be spread in the `resultObject`.

Tried the spread operator in various forms:

```js
...someData[1]  // "Property assignment expected"

[...someData[1]]  // "Expression expected"
```

Even if I only take the second prop of someData:

```js
const someData_1 = someData[1]
const resultObject = {
  address: addressObject,
  ...someData_1
}
```

Same error.

Complexity is probably in original `someData` array which has a string as first element and object as second element, which none of the other TypeScript/spread example/articles have.

Comment: `someData` has the type `(string | {age:string})[]`, so Typescript can't guarantee that `someData[1]` is indeed an object. Use `as const` or type your object explicitly.

Comment: TS is a statically typed language, and it expects the types to be known at compile time. Try use type assertion, so TS know what type of object is. Example, define the type ```interface AgeObject { age: string; }``` then type assertion ```...(someData[1] as AgeObject)```

Comment: @Blackhole the `as const` suggestion is what I would have said here also (preferable to annotations because you don't give up type inference, and preferable to assertions because you don't give up type safety). Do you want to write up an answer?

Comment: @jcalz I'll pass for this one; be my guest :).

Comment: I'll do so when I get a chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default TypeScript will infer that an [array literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#array_literals) has a plain [array type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#arrays), where each element is of the same type.  Your `someData` is therefore treated like an array where each element might be a `string` or an `{age: string}`.  The compiler intentionally doesn't keep track of which types might appear at which indices, because often people would like to change the contents of their arrays, and such information would be impossible to maintain in such a scenario (at least given TypeScript's type system, in which values types don't arbitrarily mutate).

But you don't want to use `someData` as an abitrary array of strings-or-age-havers.  Instead, you want it to be a constant set of data where the first element is a string and the second is an age-haver and there are no elements at other indices.  The inference algorithm, while reasonable for a wide range of real-world code, didn't do what you wanted.  So you need to make a change.

---

There are various ways to change the typings here. You could [annotate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables) or [assert](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) the type of `someData`.

But the easiest way to express the intent that `someData`'s structure won't change is to use a [**const assertion**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions):

```
var someData = [
    'Some String',
    { 'age': '46' }
] as const;
```

This still uses TypeScript's inference algorithm, but you're giving the compiler a hint that you don't plan to mutate the data structure and that you do care about all the literal types and their positions. Now the type of `someData` is

```
/* var someData: readonly ["Some String", {
    readonly age: "46";
}] */
```

a [tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) where the positions of the various data, including the [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html) of their string values, are known.

And now `someData[1]` is known to be an `{age: "46"}`, so you can [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) it into a new object without the compiler worrying that you might be spreading a string:

```
const resultObject = {
    address: addressObject,
    ...someData[1]
}
/* const resultObject: {
    age: "46";
    address: {
        street: string;
        number: string;
    };
} */
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/G4QwTgBAzg9gtgUwCIgC4ggXggbQFASEQDkAyvAhKamAJYB2A5sQDQFEDeJIjCxAXCQAsANmIQAvngC6EEFAgBjGPSioA3HjwB6AFQRQkWIhTpBYBCAAmKgDYBPXACJyiKjQaMnLCB3aELaztHHgRBJ1EnTQlZXW0tZVVUOSsrCygoAHkAIwArBEVk7D8iaBoEBFRBYgBZEAZ3C0rWfwh6AFc4bIQwaoBGIWI8KTxEtQh09ttUHPzCrF9W6zSEDMFl9Ky8gtQ2UoA6Q+NkNBAcPulhnX0x5Mnp2Z3BEqJQ8MjNUo3VqGfW0rUTSqZToTE+pSIHS6PUEgM84MIEmiEDiCRUsFsCH2thgjAAFPcZttCgBKIA)

Comment: Good explanation. Now I get it. Many thanks @jcalz

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
interface Address {
    street: string;
    number: string;
}

interface Age {
    age: string;
}

type SomeData = [ string, Age ]

var someData: SomeData = [
    'Some String',
    {'age': '46'}
];

const addressObject: Address = {
    street: 'Main Street',
    number: '14'
}

const resultObject = {
    address: addressObject,
    ...someData[1]
}

console.log(resultObject);
```

My output:
npx ts-node src/test.ts

```
{ address: { street: 'Main Street', number: '14' }, age: '46' }
```